# show overlay objects only around the mouse not matter where in the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, processing.js

I'm working with svg files and some processing.js code to create a homepage. 
It has some animation and static elements but the idea is to have everything the same but with different colours - Like an alternative homepage. I want this alternative to "peek" through as the mouse moves around. Only a small area around the mouse.

Does anyone have any idea how to do that? 
since it isn't an image file it's a bit tricky.

I tried doing it by using the an image and the "drawing" element of processing.js thinking it could paint the alternative homepage, however it repeats the image everywhere the mouse go and what i want is for everything to remain in the same position only show the different colours in that spot.

Comment: Concerning the last part of your question, it would be useful to actually see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider superimposing two versions of your site, the "top" one completely covering the "bottom" one (make sure all backgrounds are opaque).  Then you could try applying an SVG mask to the top page, making it transparent at a specific area and causing the bottom page to shine through.  You could modify the mask as the mouse moves.

The other way round - i.e. clipping the top layer - is also thinkable.

I see the risk that this approach is slow and not consistent across browsers - you'd have to give it a try.  Speed may differ depending on whether you clip/mask the top or the bottom layer.

- [W3C SVG Clipping, Masking and Compositing specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html)
- [MDN page on clipping and masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking)
- [MDN page on applying SVG effects to HTML content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content)

If one version of the page can be converted to other by swapping out colors, [SVG filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) might be an option as well.